# In an avm, can the horizontal space between the brackets be set manually?

Tags: spacing, matrices, linguistics, avm

I've created a simple attribute-value matrix using a custom style file `avm.sty` which is explained [here](http://www.essex.ac.uk/linguistics/external/clmt/latex4ling/avms/). However, it is so narrow that the right bracket overlaps with the text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{avm}
\begin{document}
        \begin{avm} 
    @{0} [ \asort{walk} 
           agent @{1}\\
           path @{2}\\ 
              ] 
        \end{avm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: where does this avm environment come from?

Comment: from the avm.sty package

Comment: `avm` is not on CTAN!

Comment: I got the code from a colleague so I can't change it. I installed the avm.sty file manually to be able to use it. Sorry, I'm rather new to Latex. http://nlp.stanford.edu/manning/tex/avm.sty

Comment: @Sigur: Thanks, I already managed to find out!

Comment: @LeaRebecca, your code with that style file does not work here.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have any idea what to change or add to make it work. I worked around the problem by adding white text now...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing some `&`s to separate the columns.  Also you example is missing the `\avmoptions{active}` for the short input notation:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{avm}
\avmoptions{active}

\begin{document}

\begin{avm} 
  @{0}
  [ \asort{walk}
    agent & @{1}\\
    path & @{2}\\ 
    ]
\end{avm}

\end{document}
```

See the accompanying `avm-doc.pdf` file in the `zip` file at http://nlp.stanford.edu/manning/tex/ for further examples.

Comment: yay 10 seconds too late :P